# elasticsearch, logstash and kibana to monitor a windows server

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, server, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to setup a monitoring console using ELK stack but having a few issues. i would like to display the current free disk space in a pie chart, but I'm not sure how to setup the fields to show it.

In Logstash I'm using WMI plugin to query windows information and store the logs into Elastic Search. My Logstash config looks like this.:

```
input {


  wmi{

  query => "Select Name, FreeSpace, Size from Win32_LogicalDisk where DeviceID = 'C:'"


  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    convert => [ "FreeSpace", "integer" ]
     convert => [ "Size", "integer" ]
  }
}
output{

elasticsearch{}

}
```

And in Elastic Search it's stored like this :

```
{
                "_index": "logstash-2015.04.18",
                "_type": "logs",
                "_id": "u80LfEgoQ7Omzwo3zzrvdA",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "@version": "1",
                    "@timestamp": "2015-04-18T17:15:55.634Z",
                    "host": "WIN-1N774K4CI8V",
                    "DeviceID": "C:",
                    "FreeSpace": 8467791872,
                    "Name": "C:",
                    "Size": 21367877632
                }
            }
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong i just want to show free space against hd size.

In Kibana i get a pie chart with multiple slices, where i just want 2 (free and Size).

Should i set Logstash config to store one record of diskspace and update that single record (Any help on how to do that in the config), Or should i create a scripted field in Kibana (Not sure how to do that also, any help would be great).

If anyone could point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this, that would be awesome, any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Brad

Comment: Is this Kibana 3 or 4?

Comment: Any Idea how i can accomplish this  ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and is now most likely not relevant to you but could be relevant to someone looking at this in the future.

I am assuming you want the pie chart to be free space vs used space so that the entire pie represents your whole drive.

I am running kibana 4.5.1 and it has a feature called "scripted fields" (the earliest documentation i can find with it in is 4.2) which you can create a field that is a formula of other fields in that document. This means you work out how much used space there is on your disk with `doc['Size']-doc['FreeSpace']` and with this field you create a free vs used space graph. [Click here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/4.2/managing-fields.html#create-scripted-field) for its documentation page.

You can also create scripted fields in elastic search but as I haven't done that I don't know much about it so wont comment on it but its documentation is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html)